# why i am not able to get map() method index inside of Click handler function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why I am not able to get map() method index inside of Click handler function in reactjs even i have passed index from map metho, it always returning undefined. below is my implementation url

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wu-vou3c?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The call to `toggle(index)` is wrong, the second parameter of `toggle()` method is holding index. So you need to call like `toggle('', index)`

Comment: Yes I have made the sane changes but nothing changed, you can check the updated code on same given url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the onClick should be like this:  `onClick={() => toggle(index)}` so the index is from `array.map` and i also edited your code and remove `isOpen` state. here full code:
[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-bell-mr2n7?file=/src/App.js:0-867)

Comment: Yes Thanks, Adel for your Valuable Time its working fine now,  but can you please suggest what is current & where from you are getting it in settabToggle function? as you are not using tabToggle state for changing its value

Comment: setState hooks has a callback which can access current state so `current` is the current `tabToggle` state.

Comment: okay Thaks, but why you have define condition like this 
settabToggle(current => (current === index ? undefined : index)); instead

settabToggle(current => (current === index ? index: undefined)); as we have to toggle based on matching index.

Comment: yes if the current tab is Opened and clicked again we want to close it so the condition should be `current === index?undefined:index`

Answer (score 3):

The arrow function *toggle* take 2 parameters: *element* and *index*, you're passing just index as the first parameter (that should have been element, instead), so index is undefined.

Just change your code as follow:

```
onClick={index => toggle(element, index)}
```

**UPDATE**

The code suggested is wrong as for a copy paste.

The event handler took a parameter that is the event object, you named that  parameter index, so when you pass to toggle, it use the event instead of the map index.

Anyway, toggle needs 2 parameters, so you have to pass 2.

I think the proper solution will be:

```
onClick={ev => toggle(ev.target, index)}
```

That is fine for the toggle function, but your code still has a bug, so have a look at the @adel answer.

Comment: As per my knowledge map function takes more than 2 parameters instead of Arrow, I m just receiving index from map to my arrow function, but I have made your suggested changes but nothing happened, still just returning undefined

Comment: Sorry, I notice now, you named the onClick arrow function first parameter _index_, that is the issue. I saw now @adel answered highlight that. Anyway, by adding the element as I suggested, on your code example, is not printing undefined anymore.